# How to use the first 100 data from pandas dataframe to plot sns.barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have sorted the my pandas dataframe in descending order in term of frequency as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I want to use the first 20 data `(',', 'the', '.', 'a',...)` from the sorted pandas dataframe to plot the Seaborn barplot without any labels for the x-axis ticker as well as the ticker also.

```
sns.barplot(x=pandasdf.frequency.value_counts().index[0:20],y=pandasdf.frequency.value_counts()[0:20])
```

I used the code above to plot the seaborn barplot, however, the first bar (should have the highest frequency of 61987) of the barplot (shown below) shows only 20000++ frequency instead of the bar for 61987 corresponding to the keys `','`. I'm not sure what I did wrongly, please correct me.

[image]

Also, how should I do in order to remove the tickers labels from 1 to 20 and also the ticker itself?

[image]

Comment: can't you just use `sns.barplot(x=pandasdf.index[:20],y=pandasdf.frequency[:20])`?

Comment: btw, if you'd copied the dataframe in here, instead of using an image, we could try it for ourselfs and help you better

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It works for me:) However I'm not sure how to remove the ticker for x-axis. I'm only be able to remove the x-axis ticker label by using the following code: `sns.barplot(x=pandasdf.index[:20],y=pandasdf.frequency[:20]).set_xticklabels([])` Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I am glad it helped. I think its fine to remove the ticks like this

Comment: May I know what you mean by like this? I edited the question by adding in the plot that I obtained with ticks on x-axis, how should I remove them?

Comment: Try `.set_xticks([])`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want! Thank you very much!